# XAML string format in multibinding w/converter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am implementing this TextBlock and the **stringformat** is not appearing, only the value of the binding property. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**XAML CODE**

```
<TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Text>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myConverter}">
         <Binding Path="loc.country" StringFormat="Country: {0}"/>
         <Binding Path="loc.area" StringFormat="Area: {0}"/>
       </MultiBinding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```

**Converter**

```
public class MyMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[1] == null)
            return values[0];

        return values[1];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object values, Type[] targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Best regards,

Comment: Check the **Output Window** for binding errors.

Comment: No binding errors Mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the **Remarks** section on the [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> ...
>
> When you use a MultiBinding, the StringFormat property applies
>   only when it is set on the MultiBinding. The value of StringFormat
>   that is set on any child Binding objects is ignored. ...

The reason is that `StringFormat` is only applied when the target property of the binding is actually of type `string`, which is not the case in a MultiBinding

---

So you either set the `StringFormat` of the MultiBinding (and don't set its `Converter`), or you do the formatting in your converter.

Comment: thanks for your answer. In my case, I want to show one or another...And if is the first is Country and the second it's an area. What would you recommend? (this happens in another places as well, but of simplicity purposes I didn't put it here)

Comment: You can always return a formatted string from the converter.

Comment: Done. I've done what you suggested. My thanks to you.